# How can I prefer another bin file?

Tags: bash, osx

I have installed both Wine via Homebrew and via WineBottler.

I have multiple bin files named wine.

When I run for example

```
 wine morrowind
```

It starts it with the one in `/applications/wine.app/contents/resources/bin/wine`
I want it to use `/usr/local/Cellar/wine/1.7.27/bin/wine`

I tried running this `sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/wine/1.7.27/bin/wine /usr/bin`

Symlinking it into /usr/bin but when I run `wine` it still uses the one for `wine.app`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Whats your PATH?

```
echo $PATH
```

whichever is listed first is preferred.
In your `.bashrc`, to fix your problem, set:

```
PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/wine/1.7.27/bin/:$PATH
```

Comment: This is my `$PATH` `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin`

Comment: Also. I have no file called .bashrc. Where is it supposed to be?

Comment: It solved it, it was a link in `/etc/profile`

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you can use the `PATH` environment variable to make the shell look in your local directory before `/usr/bin`. You should use `.bash_profile` for this purpose, using `.bashrc` will have some undesired side effects. Both files are located in your home directory: `/home/<your username>/.bash_profile`.

Your symlink solution also works if you want a more permanent solution, however your command will not work as it will refuse to overwrite the destination file. So you should move the original file to some safe place before running the `ln` command. You could also use the -f (force) flag to overwrite the destination file but you probably don't want that.